# How to create custom jquery scripts for Ipad in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, ipad

I have an ASP MCV 3 application which I want to access using an iPad. But I have problems with some jquery scripts which don't work on the tablet. I managed to find out a way to create custom views which will be displayed if the user open the application with an iPad.

Is there a way to do the same with jQuery files ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you provide what scripts are you having problems with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, move the part of your page that inserts the scripts into block that checks for a Razor section, and load your scripts there.

Put your new script declarations in your alternate views, and only render the standard jQuery scripts (in the layout) if the section doesn't exist on the page being rendered.

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("CustomScripts")) {
    RenderSection("CustomScripts", false);
}
else
{
   // put in your normal scripts/css here
}
```

Cheers.